# org-agenda jumps to the wrong month

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, time-date

If I try to jump (using "j") in `org-agenda` to the month September, it sometimes takes me to January. I am using org 9.4.4. If I type any of these configurations, I am still going to January:

```
sept
septe
septem
septemb
septembe
```

If I type:

```
Sep
sep
September
september
```

I go to September. Is this a bug?

Comment: Probably - there's been some churn in the `parse-time-string` function in the past year to make it grok ISO 8601 dates and the old RFC 822(ish) implementation was put into a subfunction. It may well be that something got broken in the process. Note that if it is a bug, it is an Emacs bug: use `report-emacs-bug` to report it.

Comment: on a quick check it looks that if it cannot complete (whatever it means to `org-read-date`) defaults on current date, and that's why you still get january. I'll try to take a deeper look later if no one gets it going.

Comment: @Muihlinn: try `(parse-time-string "sep")` vs `(parse-time-string "sept")`

Comment: @NickD yep, but I'm not sure if it's a bug or just something in the `org-read-date` code or documentation. Look @ var `parse-time-months` it has sep and september, nothing in-between, although not that I'm familiar with emacs parse time libs, so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following comments, it doesn't looks like a bug to me, `parse-time-months` contains "sep" and "september" nothing in between. If `org-read-date` cannot parse what you give defaults to current date (in use).

As further reference [Org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-date_002ftime-prompt.html#The-date_002ftime-prompt) says:

> The function understands English month and weekday abbreviations.
> If you want to use un-abbreviated names and/or other languages,
> configure the variables parse-time-months and parse-time-weekdays

So it is the expected behavior and I assume that there are some typos in the examples, either in the manual itself as well in the `org-read-date` docstring.

Comment: See [The Date/Time prompt](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-date_002ftime-prompt.html#The-date_002ftime-prompt): the example `‘22 sept 0:34’ ⇒ 2006-09-22 0:34` does not work any longer. It's almost certainly a change - whether it's a bug or not is debatable, but I think a bug report is indicated just to make sure. Of course, the example may be wrong.

Comment: @NickD I agree, the org manual page itself is somewhat contradictory.

Comment: I think you are right: I've looked at the git log of `parse-time.el` and I don't see any changes that would limit the set of month abbreviations accepted. I also tested it back with emacs 24.3.1 and it exhibits the same behavior, so there was no change. The example in the Date/Time prompt page is wrong.